# Why do we use GetComponent<>() on a component?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision

```
bool isRight = collision.GetComponent<Paddle>().isRight;
```

I have a script called Paddle.cs attached to a gameObject Paddle, Paddle.cs contains a field 'bool isRight;'.

This part of the code detects which object is colliding with the current object.

I don't understand this part

```
collision.GetComponent<Paddle>().isRight;
```

Here is my script

```
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    if(collision.tag == "Paddle")
    {
        bool isRight = collision.GetComponent<Paddle>().isRight;

        if (isRight)
        {
            direction.x *= -1;
        }
        if (!isRight)
        {
            direction.x *= -1;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Because in Unity both exist: [`GameObject.GetComponent`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponent.html) and also  [`Component.GetComponent`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.GetComponent.html)

*[`Collider2D`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider2D.html) as well as [`MonoBehaviour`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.html) inherit from [`Behaviour`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Behaviour.html) which inherits from [`Component`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.html)*

[Internally](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference/blob/9034442437e6b5efe28c51d02e978a96a3ce5439/Runtime/Export/Scripting/Component.bindings.cs) it is basically kind of a shortcut and afaik behaves exactly the same so it makes no real difference whether you use

```
collision.GetComponent<XY>()
```

or

```
collision.gameObject.GetComponent<XY>()
```

---

That's also the reason why you usually simply use

```
var someComponent = GetComponent<SomeComponent>();
```

in your scripts instead of having to go through

```
var someComponent = gameObject.GetComponent<SomeComponent>();
```

---

in general: Since there is also `OnCollisionEnter` using the class `Collision` just to avoid confusions you should rather call your parameter `Collider2D collider` or usually (in the docs) it is `other`.

Comment: For example GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>() returns a rigidbody component, but in this case it returns a gameObject 'Paddle', that's the part that i don't understand

Comment: It doesn't return a `GameObject` .. the `name` you can see in logs etc is the name of the `GameObject`! But the type is a `Paddle` reference!

Answer (score 0):

We use [Component.GetComponent](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.GetComponent.html) as a shortcut for [GameObject.GetComponent](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponent.html).

It allows you to get a component on the same GameObject the script is attached to without having to explicitly reference the object itself. In other words, simplifying the code from

```
var someComponent = gameObject.GetComponent<SomeComponent>();
```

to

```
var someComponent = GetComponent<SomeComponent>();
```

The two methods are functionally identical.

You can find the source-code in the [UnityCsReference page on github](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference/blob/9034442437e6b5efe28c51d02e978a96a3ce5439/Runtime/Export/Scripting/Component.bindings.cs), although, as I understand it, it's just a wrapper for native (C++, platform-specific) code. Specifically, it's calling `GameObjectBindings::GetComponentFromType`.